# showing double dates in post detail page WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have install WordPress 6.0 in my local system. and just open default post (Hello world),
in post showing double dates of post.
I have research for 2 hours and get a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case I have add below code in my function.php file. ang get only one Published date

```
function jl_remove_post_dates() {
   add_filter('the_modified_date', '__return_false');
   add_filter('get_the_modified_date', '__return_false')
}
```

Source : https://wordpress.com/forums/topic/date-appears-two-times-after-editing-an-article/